# Stored Procedure always returning 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get returned value from stored procedure, but it always returning 0.

### c# code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "AbsentEntry";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ViewState["empID"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AttendanceDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnval", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int result = (int)cmd.Parameters["@returnval"].Value;
    return result;
```

### SP

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AbsentEntry] 
@EmpID varchar(10), 
@AttendanceDate Date 

AS BEGIN
declare @returnval     int 
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEmpAttendance WHERE EmpID = @EmpID AND AttendanceDate=@AttendanceDate) = 0
    BEGIN
        insert into tblEmpAttendance (EmpID, AttendanceDate, IsInOut, SessionCount, IsPresent) values ( @EmpID,@AttendanceDate,'OUT',0,'A')
        set @returnval=1
    return @returnval
     END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       set @returnval=0 
    return @returnval
    END
END
```

In all cases, it is returning 0 . i cant figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a similar code like yours and it works as expected.
However, in your code there is a call to ExecuteNonQuery two times.

When the first call is made the record is inserted as expected, then you add the parameter for the return value and execute again the command. But now the record exists and the stored procedure falls always in the else block thus returning always zero.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "AbsentEntry";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ViewState["empID"].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AttendanceDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnval", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int result = (int)cmd.Parameters["@returnval"].Value;
return result;
```

Comment: thanks. i was suffering from last 2 hours for this silly typing error.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using executenonquery.

You should use executescalar to Return a single value.

Comment: I want returning value of SP, not ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteScaler value. See the code again and find the missing plz

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an out parameter in your stored procedure, and you are using ExecuteNonQuery -- basically, client side you aren't giving the reurn value anywhere to go.  In C# terms it's as if you called a function, but didn't make it part of an assignment.  x=getX(); vs getX();

You can fix this by either changing the stored procedure sothat it has an output parameter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AbsentEntry] 
    @EmpID varchar(10), 
    @AttendanceDate Date,
    @returnval     int OUTPUT

AS BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEmpAttendance 
        WHERE EmpID = @EmpID AND AttendanceDate=@AttendanceDate) = 0
    BEGIN
        insert into tblEmpAttendance (EmpID, AttendanceDate, IsInOut,
        SessionCount, IsPresent) values ( @EmpID,@AttendanceDate,'OUT',0,'A')
        set @returnval=1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       set @returnval=0 
    END
END
```

Or, more simply, by using ExecuteScalar and assign the result to a variable.

```
int result = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Answer (score 0):

if count is in your select query u should used executescaler.. like

```
int result=convert.toint32(cmd.executescalar());
```

or

```
int result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```